# VC++ 2010 template typedef typename error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010, wtl, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to migrate a project to VC++ 2010 
The project contains the file TabbedMDI.h (by Danial Bowen) which gives the error "named followd by '::' must be a class or namespace name for the line 
"typedef typename TClient::TTabCtrl TTabCtrl;"

code snipit follows

```
template <
    class T,
    class TClient = CTabbedMDIClient< CDotNetTabCtrl<CTabViewTabItem> >,
    class TBase = WTL::CMDIWindow,
    class TWinTraits = ATL::CFrameWinTraits>
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CTabbedMDIFrameWindowImpl :
    public WTL::CMDIFrameWindowImpl<T, TBase, TWinTraits >
{
public:
    // Expose the type of MDI client
    typedef typename TClient TClient;
    // Expose the type of tab control
    typedef typename TClient::TTabCtrl TTabCtrl;

// Member variables
protected:
    TClient m_tabbedClient;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compiled Daniel's **SimpleTabbedMDIDemo** sample from [Custom Tab Controls, Tabbed Frame and Tabbed MDI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/tabbingframework.aspx) with VC2010 Express (WTL 8.1, ATL 8.00 from WinDDK) without problem (except manifest duplication). 
Your problem is elsewhere.

**[Edit]**
Do you use the latest *TabbedMDI.h*? mine has:

```
// History (Date/Author/Description):
// ----------------------------------
//
// 2005/07/13: Daniel Bowen
// - Namespace qualify the use of more ATL and WTL classes.
// - CTabbedMDIFrameWindowImpl:
//   * Add GetMDITabCtrl
```